# Crystal - Select a Specific Field Value based on Another value within the same table

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to add a formula in my report that looks at a table with multiple values and returns the value that matches my if statement.

Here is a sample of the table (selections) data

#### Customer --   ItemID  -- Field1

12 _________      05 ______      Red

12_________       06 ______       Blue

12_________      07 ______       Green

12 _________       08 ______      Black

The customer number is already being passed into the report.  When I add this value to the report, it properly lists 12

Now, I want to add a formulas that says  "if ({Selections.ItemID}=05) then selections.Field1 else '0'

In SQl, this works.. it knows that customer is 12 and ItemID is 5, so when I use (select Field1 from selections where customer=12 and itemID=5) only the single value (red) is returned in the query results

Whenever I add this formula into my report, however, it only displays 0.
If I just add Field 1 into the report, only the top value is returned.

What needs to be done for this 'logic lookup' to work.  I want to be able to add multiple lines to the if/then that checks for each ItemID value and then displays the corresponding Field1 data for that value.

Comment: to post your code if you have ,because it will be useful to handle your question

Comment: here is the exact Formula that I am using

if ({CustomerGROUPINFO.ITEMID}='25-Siding') then {CUSTOMERGROUPINFO.FIELD1} else 'test'

Answer (score 0):

I would comment if I could, but I had an issue with crystal reports if statements when I tried to return a string if true and a number if false. The if statement can only return one data type, so if true is returning a number (id) and false is returning the string 'test' you need to convert the id to a string.

See if this works.

```
if ({CustomerGROUPINFO.ITEMID}='25-Siding') then ToText({CUSTOMERGROUPINFO.FIELD1}) else 'test'
```